# Can someone check to see what is wrong with my expression?

Tags: regex, vi

I am trying to change these:

http://www.ltv.com/iloveu/health/contraceptionsurvey/

http://www.ltv.com/iloveu/health/contraception-special/

```
 location ~* ^/iloveu/health/contraceptionsurvey/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /ilo`enter code here`veu/health/ permanent;
    }

    location ~* ^/iloveu/health/contraception-special/?$ {
        rewrite ^ /iloveu/health/ permanent;

}
```

with this expression that I have created:

```
%s/http:\/\/www\.ltv\.com\(.*\)/location ~\* \^\& \{ \r\t rewrite \^ \/iloveu\/health\/ permanent; \r }\r/g
```

But don't seem to be getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
%s#http://www\.ltv\.com\(.*\)#location \~* ^\1?$ \{ \r\t rewrite ^ /iloveu/health/ permanent; \r }\r#g
```

`\&` gets the whole string that that was matched, not just the part in parentheses, you get that with `\1`.